# Showing that $H_{dR}^1(T) \neq 0$ where $T = \mathbb{C} / ( \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}*i)$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I want to show that the $S^2$ isn't diffeomorphic to complex torus.I just want to understand why $H_{dR}^1(T) \neq 0$. If someone could explain it in details that would be nice since we didn't cover the details of calculation in my class as much as I wanted to.

Comment: You know that there are very many more elementary ways of showing that the sphere isn't diffeomorphic to the torus?  In fact they aren't even homeomorphic.

Comment: I would like to do it using deRham cohomology.

Comment: [This](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/10/12/the-cohomology-of-the-n-torus/) appears to calculate the de Rham cohomology of $S^n$.

Comment: @Mark: That does indeed do it, although the notation of your comment seems to depend on a dubious pun $(S^1)^n = S^n$.